# How to migrate a mailbox to exchange online from on premises without removing private internal domain addresses

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

I have two tenants (among others) that use a special private DNS to send email over non-internet routes. Every mailbox has an address on that domain assigned to it. so if we say company.com is the public domain, and company.r.private is the private domain.

In one tenant I helped them migrate to Exchange online and the mailboxes seem to just strip the private domain address(es) from the mailbox, since the private domain isn't an accepted domain in EOL. I've completed migration here and all is good. The private addresses remain in the on-prem "remotemailbox" entry, so mail sent to the private internal address can be delivered to them. I use a connector in EOL to direct mail sent to *.r.private down to the on prem exchange where it can either be passed onto to another server in the r.private network, or back up to EOL for delivery based on the targetAddress attribute in on prem AD.

In the other tenant our test user isn't migrating because I get a "nonaccepteddomain" error. Rather than strip the non-accepted domains, it simply refuses to migrate. Every site I get through google tells me to simply remove the offending domain(s). That's not an acceptable solution for me, and clearly I've made it work in the past. I just can't figure out what I did!

Edit:
The full error is:
Error: NotAcceptedDomainException: You can't use the domain company.r.private because it's not an accepted domain for your organization.

Comment: Can you share the detailed message of the "nonaccepreddomain" error? Remember to remore the priavate information involed.

Comment: Sure thing. I've edited the original post.

Comment: Are we talking about a non routable domain here?

Answer (score 0):

Non routable domains are not supported by Exchange Online, so they will always be removed automatically, it's built in the service. Also check the docs about non routable domains

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/prepare-a-non-routable-domain-for-directory-synchronization?view=o365-worldwide